# Guava predicate to filter various conditions without anonymous class or extra classes

Tags: java, guava

***With Java 6 and Guava 12.0*** I am trying to filter a list of Strings based on if they have a specific prefix or not. Is there a way to do this without using anonymous classes or a separate class for each distinct prefix I want?

This works but it's ugly (even uglier with my company's imposed formatting I've removed).

```
private String foo(String prefix, List<String> stuff) {

    Collection<String> withPrefix = Collections2.filter(stuff, new Predicate<String>() {
        @Override
        public boolean apply(String input) {
            return input.startsWith(prefix);
        }
    });
    //...
}
```

Of course I could do something like the following.

```
public class PrefixCheckForAA implements Predicate<String> {

    @Override
    public boolean apply(String input) {
        return input.startsWith("AA");
    }
}

public class PrefixCheckForZZ implements Predicate<String> {

    @Override
    public boolean apply(String input) {
        return input.startsWith("ZZ");
    }
}
```

Is there any way to do this without anonymous classes or a bunch of seemingly redundant classes?

Comment: Is moving to Java 8 impossible? (Not that I have anything against guava!)

Comment: @scribaniwannabe For me, yes. That's why I emphasized java 6 in the question. It doesn't even seem like we're going to java 7 anytime soon either.

Comment: Understood. While it is a shame you cannot upgrade I too work in industry and know that sometimes it just isn't an option. That being said, [your own answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30538454/guava-predicate-to-filter-various-conditions-without-anonymous-class-or-extra-cl#answer-30538455) is very well done below. I am a big supporter of the Guava libraries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While your own solution is perfectly valid, you can slim down your code even further by using Guava library functionality:

```
Collection<String> withPrefix = Collections2.filter(stuff, Predicates.containsPattern("^AA"));
```

For a list of all functionality of `Predicates`, please go [here](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Predicates.html).

Comment: Edit it to `"^" + prefix` instead, that way the prefix is a variable.

Answer (score 4):

I found a solution while writing this, I can't believe I was so silly to not think of this...

Simply make the class have a constructor that requires a String, use this String as the prefix to check for.

```
public class PrefixChecker implements Predicate<String> {

    private final String prefix;

    public Prefix(String prefix) {
        this.prefix = prefix;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean apply(String input) {
        return input.startsWith(prefix);
    }
}
```